# Add “Read More/Read Less” to any text in Javascript or JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to create a Read More/Read Less. My actual problem is, or example i have 5 container with readmore text if i click on readmore text all of containers exapand all together
but i want to expand clicked container not all of them

**This is my code:**

codepen:
https://codepen.io/meysamrad/pen/WNPyKaw

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   // resize the slide-read-more Div
   var box = $(".slide-read-more");
   var minimumHeight = 200; // max height in pixels
   var initialHeight = box.innerHeight();
   // reduce the text if it's longer than 200px
   if (initialHeight > minimumHeight) {
      box.css('height', minimumHeight);
      $(".read-more-button").show();
   }
  
   SliderReadMore();

   function SliderReadMore() {
      $(".slide-read-more-button").on('click', function () {
         // get current height
         var currentHeight = box.innerHeight();

         // get height with auto applied
         var autoHeight = box.css('height', 'auto').innerHeight();

         // reset height and revert to original if current and auto are equal
         var newHeight = (currentHeight | 0) === (autoHeight | 0) ? minimumHeight : autoHeight;

         box.css('height', currentHeight).animate({
            height: (newHeight)
         })
         $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: box.offset().top
         });
        $(".slide-read-more-button").toggle();
      });
   }
});
```

```css
main{
  max-width: 600px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.slide-read-more{
    overflow:hidden;
}
.slide-read-more-button{
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: right;
    margin-top: 8px;
    color: #488A8A;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main>
<p class="slide-read-more">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
 It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
 It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
</p>
<div class="slide-read-more-button read-more-button">Read More</div>
<div class="slide-read-more-button">Read Less</div>
  
  
  <p class="slide-read-more">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
 It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
 It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
</p>
<div class="slide-read-more-button read-more-button">Read More</div>
<div class="slide-read-more-button">Read Less</div>
</main>
```

Please tell me the best solution for jQuery or Javascript?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the next() function to select the corresponding button and adjusting the event listener accordingly.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(".slide-read-more").each(function () {
        let box = $(this);
        let minimumHeight = 200; // max height in pixels
        let initialHeight = box.innerHeight();

        // reduce the text if it's longer than 200px
        if (initialHeight > minimumHeight) {
            box.css('height', minimumHeight);
            $(this).next(".slide-read-more-button.read-more-button").show();
        }

        let readMoreButton = $(this).next(".slide-read-more-button.read-more-button");

        readMoreButton.on('click', function () {
            let currentHeight = box.innerHeight();
            let autoHeight = box.css('height', 'auto').innerHeight();
            let newHeight = (currentHeight | 0) === (autoHeight | 0) ? minimumHeight : autoHeight;

            box.css('height', currentHeight).animate({
                height: newHeight
            });

            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: box.offset().top
            });

            toggleText(readMoreButton);
        });
    });

    function toggleText(button) {
        let buttonText = button.text();
        button.text(buttonText === "Read More" ? "Read Less" : "Read More");
    }
});
```